# Strange fluid sim behaviour

Tags: fluid-simulation

Good day.

I found another member had the same prob twi years ago. Maybe someone can help me this time.

THe prob is the following:

I got (now) a simple setup with a bowl (acting as fluid->obstacle) and some water in it (fluid->fluid). The scene is surrounded by a cube (acting as fluid->domain). Last object is the camera.

I reduced my scene to only this four objects to reduce possible error sources.

Now when I'm start the baking process, this is the first frame after the simulation starts: 
[image: Strange shape]

It is not my first fluid sim and I never had such a problem before. Setting are pretty much default. Any hints on this?

Comment: Is your domain big enough to encompass all objects? Do all objects have applied rotation and scale?

Comment: Yes and yes! Domain is big enough, Rotation & Scale applied.

Comment: I just tried a similar setup... it works, so it could be just your file/setup: can you share it on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post the link here?

Comment: I tried to upload it to Blend-Exchange, but it caused errors. I uploaded it to my google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B68Wl-5lW3EkUkEzZWM3MHBrWDg

btw: this is another file where I just tried to do everything again in a complete new file. Behaviouir is just the same. So I must have done something wrong that I am constantly overlooking.

Answer (score 2):

YES! I solved the problem. Thanks to sardipax! It was very simple: the normals ofc were facing inwards bcs. I created the water mesh from the bowl/glas. Flipping the normals solved this issue.

Thanks for everyone who took care here.

Damned what a wasted night just because of such a simple mistake ... ;-)